# Можно ли вернуться в блок try из блока except после обработки исключения?Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

Вот собственно сам код

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from random import choice
from time import sleep
from random import uniform
import json

def get_html(url,useragent,proxy,StartFroms):

    print("get_html")
    print(StartFroms)
    print(proxy)
    s = requests.Session()
    s.get("http://toto-info.co",proxies = proxy)

    pl = {"options": {"DrawingId": 629, "StartFrom":StartFroms, "Count": 100, "SortField": "CouponCode", "SortDir": "ASC"}}
    res = s.post(url, headers={'User-Agent':useragent,
                'Accept-Language' : 'ru,en;q=0.8',
                'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
                'Connection': 'keep - alive',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Host': 'old.toto-info.co',
                'Origin': 'http://toto-info.co',
                'Referer': 'http://toto-info.co/'},proxies = proxy, data=json.dumps(pl))

    print(res.text)
    print('------------------------------------------')

#def parse(html):

    #soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

def main():

    url = 'http://old.toto-info.co/DataService.svc/GetMaxPrizeCoupons'

    useragents = open("useragents.txt").read().split('\n')
    proxies = open("proxies.txt").read().split('\n')

    for i in range(0,931,20):

        StartFroms = i
        useragent = "'"+choice(useragents)+"'"
        proxy = {'http': 'http://' + choice(proxies)}
        try:
            get_html(url,useragent,proxy,StartFroms)
        except:
            print("Not working, man, please stop..")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: А кто вам запретит?

Comment: А каким образом это можно сделать? Просто я чёт погуглил, ничего не смог найти.@AGS17

Comment: Обычным циклом, повторным вызовом и тд. Зависит от задачи

Comment: Окей, а как можно сделать, чтоб он не начинал каждый раз цикл с 0 
 а продолжал с того места где вышло исключение?@AGS17

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под _продолжал с того места где вышло исключение_?

Comment: ну вот у меня идёт цикл от 0 с шагом 20, он дошёл допустим до 60, и тут вышло  исключение, и цикл снова начался с 0, а мне хотелось бы чтоб он продолжался с 60?просто в цикле я меняю ip и некоторые из них не отвечают, после чего выходит исключение, и он снова начинает с 0 @AGS17

Comment: Вообще-то цикл должен продолжать исполнение.

Comment: Да он продолжает, но грубо говоря он пропускает ту страницу на которой вышло исключение, а я хочу чтобы он снова попробовал спарсить эту страницу но уже с другим ip @Alex78191

Comment: @ПашаВасильев цикл `for i in range(0,931,20):` должен перейти к следующей итерации с другим IP.

Comment: yeld посмотрите